# Dynamic memory allocation giving access violation(s)

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My code keeps breaking (i.e. throwing me an access violation exception) when I allocate room for a buffer in my hex array.

I declare the hex array as a two star pointer in main and pass it in by reference.

**Somewhere in main.cpp**

```
char ** hexArray = nullptr;
```

**Somewhere in fileio.cpp**

```
void TranslateFile(char * byteArray, char **& hexArray, int numberOfBytes, char buffer[])
{
int temp = 0;

//Convert bytes into hexadecimal
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBytes; i++)
{
    //Convert byteArray to decimal
     atoi(&byteArray[i]);

     //Set temp equal to byteArray
     temp = byteArray[i];

     //Convert temp to hexadecimal and store it in hex array
     itoa(temp, buffer, 16);

     //Allocate room for buffer
     hexArray[i] = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1]; //CODE BREAKS HERE

     //Copy buffer into newly allocated spot
     strcpy(hexArray[i], buffer);
}
}
```

Comment: try to use C++ instead of C, e.g. `vector<string> hexArray;`.

Comment: Are you allocating `hexArray` anywhere? you can't assign to `hexArray[i]` unless you've already done a `hexArray = new char*[count]` somewhere first

Comment: wow 5 answers in 5 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

```
char ** hexArray = nullptr;
```

`hexArray` is uninitialized.

```
hexArray[i] = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1]; //CODE BREAKS HERE
```

You dereference `hexArray`, but it is uninitialized, and thus your program yields undefined behavior.  You need to initialize it and, per your code sample, it must point to *at least* `numberOfBytes` elements.

```
hexArray = new char *[numberOfBytes];
```

Now `hexArray` is an initialized pointer which points to `numberOfBytes` uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @MrPickle5: Don't forget, what has been `new[]`ed must be `delete[]`d. Smart pointers are one approach but in this case, `std::vector<std::string>` would arguably be a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for the outer array.
From your example, it is probably:

```
hexArray = new char *[numberOfBytes];
```

Comment: sounds like you need to allocate more memory for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

`char **` is either an array of `char *` or is a pointer to a `char *`.  Either way, you need to allocate something before you can do `hexArray[i]`.

somewhere in main.cpp:

```
hexArray = new char *[NUM_CHAR_PTRS];
```

Later...

```
hexArray[i] = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate space for the `hexArray` itself. What you done in

```
 //Allocate room for buffer
 hexArray[i] = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1]; //CODE BREAKS HERE
```

is allocating memory for elements of the `hexArray`.

So you should put the code:

```
hexArray = new char*[numberOfBytes];
```

before entering the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have `numberOfBytes` entries in `hexArray` already been allocated?

Use `strnlen` instead of `strlen` or better still `std::string`.  Do you know whether `buffer` is terminated or not (that is, is it part of `TranslateFile`'s contract)?